# ListVectorPlot have to be run twice to get the plot

Tags: plotting

I'm running the following code on v10

```
w = 340*^-6;
h = 150*^-6;
d = w - 2 h;
data = Import["datafilt.txt", "Table"];
fig = ListVectorPlot[{data[[;; , {1, 
        2}]], data[[;; , {5, 6}]]}\[Transpose], 
   PlotRange -> {{-w/2, w/2}, {-h, 0}}]
```

I have to run the code twice to get the vector plot. ListStreamPlot does not show the result at all.

Data in
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ll9hb3oxxreufsg/AABvU7nufHhyHY3W4ausanJ6a?dl=0

Any idea what is going wrong?

Edit: the question has been marked as duplicate. However I first obtain the crash and then I have to rerun the code to obtain the plot, while the other discussion claims that after two runs the kernel crashes. It is not the same since I start from a not running kernel.

Comment: Please provide sample `data`.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: update the post with sample data and cleaned the code from bothering stuff.

Comment: I started with the original code in the question, then revised it a few times as the code was changed, and the Kernel started crashing.  So, I restarted Mathematica and all was well, producing what I believe is the desired plot.  I suggest that you restart Mathematica and then try the updated code.

Comment: As to `ListStreamPlot`, what code are you using?

Comment: I've simply substituted ListVectorPlot with ListStreamPlot. Should be ok, isn't that? I've tried to restart M but the problem persists.

Comment: Yes, it should, but it causes my Kernel to crash reproducibly.  Is `ListVectorPlot` working properly after you restarted Mathematica?  By the way, I have `$Version` "10.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (October 9, 2015)".

Comment: No it is not working. I've closed and restarted but still I have the problem. You're right the kernel is crashing without any further evidence, like messagges in the terminal. I have "10.1.0  for Linux x86 (64-bit) (March 24, 2015)".

Comment: It plots fine for me. Check and make sure your data looks right --Dimensions[data] is {466, 6}.

Comment: @bill s: Yes Dimensions are those. Which version are you using? Could you do ListStreamPlot?

Comment: 10.3 on a Mac 10.11. ListStreamPlot does not work -- crashes kernel.

Comment: Can we say this is a bug or something specific about the dataset we are using?

Comment: Oh yeah, http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/98755/listvectorplot-crashes-kernel-after-two-evaluations